# changing favicon in joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.6

How can we change the favicon in Joomla 1.6?

Do I just create a  16x16 px images, convert it to a .ico format and store it as

favicon.ico under images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store file favicon.ico in your template root folder. (/templates/template_name)

And - browsers like to cache favicons, so you should clean your browser's cache or wait to see the results.